# Display elements inline in mobile view when using bootstrap navbar collapse

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have trouble understanding how to properly align social media icons (left) and logo (center) in mobile / table view in bootstrap. I want the logo and some icons beside the burger menu to be visible even when switching to mobile view, but it does not align properly for me and it shows vertically instead of horizontally when going into mobile view.

Desktop View:
[image: Bootstrap nav menu Desktop View]

Mobile View:
[image: Bootstrap nav menu Mobile View]
This is my css/html:

```css
/* Style for "Signup Rectangle" */
.sign-up:hover, .log-in:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style for "SIGN UP" */
.sign-up {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Style for "LOG IN" */

.log-in {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Style for "Linkedin, Twitter, Facebook" */
.instagram-logo, .twitter-logo, .facebook-logo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 21px;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.logo {
  width: 128px;
  height: 53px;
}

.navbar-container {
  padding-top: 18px !important;
}

.panorama {
  padding-top: 140px;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.affix {
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;
}

.affix-top {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color:#fff !important;
}

.affix-top .nav > li > a {
   color: #000;
   filter: invert(100%);
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.affix-top .navbar-collapse {
   border-color: transparent;
   box-shadow: initial;
}

/*************MEDIA QUERIES **************/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-container">
            <li><a href="#"><img class="instagram-logo" src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'instagram.png']) }}"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="facebook-logo" src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'facebook.png']) }}"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="twitter-logo" src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'twitter.png']) }}"></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-header navbar-center">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img class="na-logo" alt="" src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'logo.png']) }}">
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav navbar-container">
            <li>
              <a class="sign-up">SIGN UP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="log-in">LOG IN</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Mobile Burger Menu -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-burger-menu">
              <span class="sr-only">Navigation Menu</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="navbar-burger-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <!-- Mobile Burger Menu End -->
        <!-- Mobile / Table view End -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <section class="panorama" style="background: url({{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'panorama.png']) }}) no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center;">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Hello.</h1>
    </div>
  </section><!-- panorama navigation section end -->
</nav><!-- .navbar end -->
```

Anyone can help out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here ya go. Left menu on left, logo centered, login on right. Hamburger stack below that opens a full width menu.

I floated the left menu to the left and the right one to the right. To get the logo centered in the middle I positioned it absolutely and then set it 50% from the left, minus half the width of the logo. I took off the navbar default to get rid of the gray background that bootstrap automatically puts on it. Also took the collapse off of the navbar-collapse div that the top three ul's were inside of. That way it wouldn't disappear when on mobile. I made the li's inside of the left and right menu be display inline block so they would links would be beside each other. Since the dropdown menu for your hamburger stack is positioned absolutely, I added a right:0 to make it fI'll width. I think that was almost everything.

```css
.navbar-left{
  float:left;
}
.navbar-left.nav>li, .navbar-right.nav>li{
  display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-right{
  float:right;
}
.navbar-center{
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
}
#navbar-burger-menu{
  right:0;
}
/* Style for "Signup Rectangle" */
.sign-up:hover, .log-in:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}

/* Style for "SIGN UP" */
.sign-up {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Style for "LOG IN" */

.log-in {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Style for "Linkedin, Twitter, Facebook" */
.instagram-logo, .twitter-logo, .facebook-logo{
  width: 20px;
  height: 21px;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.logo {
  width: 128px;
  height: 53px;
}

.navbar-container {
  padding-top:18px !important;
}

.panorama {
  padding-top:140px;
  height:100vh;
  min-height:400px;
}

.affix {
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;
  transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;
}

.affix-top {
  background:transparent;
  border-color:transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color:#fff !important;
}

.affix-top .nav > li > a {
  color: #000;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-bottom:35px;
}

.affix-top .navbar-collapse {
  border-color:transparent;
  box-shadow:initial;
}

/*************MEDIA QUERIES **************/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse ">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-container navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#"><img class="instagram-logo" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="facebook-logo" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="twitter-logo" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-header navbar-center">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img class="na-logo" alt="" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/50/50">
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav navbar-container">
            <li>
              <a class="sign-up">SIGN UP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="log-in">LOG IN</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Mobile Burger Menu -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-burger-menu">
              <span class="sr-only">Navigation Menu</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="navbar-burger-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <!-- Mobile Burger Menu End -->
        <!-- Mobile / Table view End -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <section class="panorama" style="background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300) no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center;">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Hello.</h1>
    </div>
  </section><!-- panorama navigation section end -->
</nav><!-- .navbar end -->
```

Comment: I did post all the relevant css I created to date, yes. I would probably want to implement a proper hamburger menu yes, but haven't started with this yet. My main issue still remains which is to properly align my elements when being in mobile / tablet view :) but ofc if you have some input on implementing the burger menu, I am glad for any input.

Comment: It's just that when I added the bootstrap css and js and jquery, it was automatically working. If the hamburger menu is going to be there, where would it be? would it be under the main top line or inline at the top?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for :]

Comment: hey! thanks for this, it does work, what did you do now to make it work? Could you explain a bit so I get it as well? ;)

Comment: Yes, I was in a rush before and didn't get a chance to. I'll update my answer

Comment: Please accept this answer if it works for you then :]